# How do you include both zh_TW and zh_HK localizations in Xcode

Tags: iphone, localization

Hi I'm trying to add localizations for Taiwan Traditional Mandarin (zh_TW) and Hong Kong Cantonese (zh_HK) to my iPhone app and I'm having trouble getting both localizations into the same project.  When both localizations are included the Taiwan takes precedence but when just Hong Kong is included it works fine. I put my phone into Hant, and change the region either to Hong Kong SAR or Taiwan.

I've tried a number of different lproj file names, zh_TW.lproj, zh-Hant.lproj, zh-Hant_TW.lproj, zh_HK.lproj, and zh-Hant_HK.lproj.

I've looked at the iphone documentation and there is little information about naming lproj files and localization. It says that you should use zh-hant instead of zh_TW and there is information about including a region after the language, so I thought maybe zh-Hant_TW and HK might work but they don't change depending on what region the phone is in.

I've also looked at the [NSLocale canonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString:] for both zh_TW and zh_HK, both return zh-Hant, and the [NSLocale canonicalLocaleIdentifierFromString:] returns zh_TW and zh_HK respectively.

So my question is what do I need to name the lproj files to allow me to use both Taiwan and Hong Kong localizations.

Comment: It was a while ago that I had a similar issue to this - I seem to recall the solution that worked for me was to change the file encoding of the strings files in Xcode to be Unicode UTF-16. I can't recall what lproj names I used, apologies. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`, the codes would be `zh_Hant_TW` and `zh_Hant_HK`. In your example, you used a dash in place of that first underscore.